# Use SurveyJS along with Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, surveyjs

As knows `NextJS` is using the server side rendering, I want to use `SurveyJs` with it but `surveyJS` is using some function that must be executed in client side. In my case I wanna use `StylesManager.applyTheme` but it throws an server error of `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

any possible way can I use to execute the `applyTheme` function in client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better implementation, I solved the issue using dynamic imports from `NextJs`

Instead, I imported my `SurveyComponent` like this:

```js
const SurveyComponent = dynamic(
  () => import("../../../../components/survey/PartOne"),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```

To make sure my `SurveyComponent` does not render on server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this creating a useEffect Hook that consumes an external function to apply this theme:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'

useEffect(() => {
  const newSurveyCreator = new SurveyJSCreator.SurveyCreator('surveyCreatorContainer', surveyCreatorConfig);
  
  newSurveyCreator.saveSurveyFunc = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this && this.text);
  };
    
  updateSurveyCreator(newSurveyCreator);

}, []);
```

Comment: I just executed the `StylesManager.applyTheme` function inside the `useEffect` hook and it worked.